# Передача кода для размещения на сайте

Tags: c#, asp.net

Я создала проект C# asp.net web forms.
Пишу страничку для записи.
В будущем её планируется разместить на сайте.
Те, кто сайтом занимаются должны на своей стороне вставить мой код.
Мне непонятно, в каком виде мне нужно будет передавать код - полностью проект?
Кто-нибудь может объяснить?

Comment: Думаю, можно в IIS в существующий сайт добавить приложение. Вы свой проект передаете в скомпилированном виде, так же, как и когда вы его просто публикуете в виде самостоятельного сайта.

Comment: Можно передать скомпилированный проект, можно полностью.
Но главное убедится что сайт основан на .NET, а не например на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку ваш проект написан на asp.net, то чтобы запустить его, необходимо скомпилировать и развернуть приложение в службу IIS.
Из Visual Studio вам доступно несколько способов публикации приложения:

- Web Deploy - развертывания приложения напрямую в IIS, который настроен
  на приём удаленных Web Deploy запросов.
- Web Deploy Package - развертывания приложения через пакет
  развёртывания, который необходимо загрузить вручную на сервер и
  добавить в IIS.
- FTP - развертывание приложения через FTP-сервер.
- File System - развертывание приложения в файловую систему текущего
  компьютера.

Способ развертывания напрямую зависит от того, куда вы разворачиваете приложение: IIS настроенный локально, на отдельный Windows Server, на удаленный хостинг и др.

Очень много информации можно найти по запросу "Публикация приложения asp.net web forms".